# Ruby gem install error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

This is an error snippet:

```
Using jbuilder (1.5.3) Installing jquery-rails (3.1.0) Installing json (1.8.1) Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR:
Failed to build gem native extension .

    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/ruby.exe: No such file or directory
-- extconf.r b (LoadError)

Gem files will remain installed in
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9 .1/gems/json-1.8.1 for
inspection. Results logged to
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.
1/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out An error occurred while
installing json (1.8.1), and Bundler cannot continue. Make sure that
`gem install json -v '1.8.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Entering `gem install json -v` returns:

```
'1.8.1' Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit... Building
native extensions.  This could take a while... ERROR:  Error
installing json:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/ruby.exe: No such file or directory
-- extconf.r b (LoadError)


Gem files will remain installed in
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9 .1/gems/json-1.8.1 for
inspection. Results logged to
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.
1/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out
```

Entering `bundle install` returns:

```
Bundler::GemfileNotFound
```

Entering `cd qwerty` returns:

```
pmakamgovind@CSCINDAE751352 ~/Desktop/ruby/qwerty $ rails s
←[31mCould not find gem 'rails (= 4.0.2) x86-mingw32' in the gems
available on t his machine.←[0m ←[33mRun `bundle install` to install
missing gems.←[0m
```

Comment: i think u are installing bundle gems from wrong directory, if u have created a new rails app then cd into it, then do bundle install

Comment: have you use rvm/rbenv?

Comment: What environment do you have? Windows / Linux?

Comment: Rich, I am on Windows.

Comment: Rahul, I cd'ed in to the proj folder, verified the line gem 'json', '1.8.1'. Then, I tried running bundle install

Comment: Manb, I dono this. I installed the env using rails installer from rails installer.org. It has done the job for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this line on your Gemfile:
`gem 'json', '1.8.1'`

Then run: `bundle update` to overwrite the newer version of the json gem.

Comment: I have added this line in the gemfile and saved. Tried running "bundle install" too.. Still it shows as below.

pmakamgovind@CSCINDAE751352 ~/Desktop/ruby/qwerty
$ bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Could not find gem 'Json (= 1.8.1) x86-mingw32' in the gems available on this
machine.

Answer (score 0):

If the number of gems you have used aren't really huge, then you can directly mention the Github path and continue with it.

Or, download the Github copy of the particular gems in question and make a local copy for your own use. That way you don't have to be dependent on rubygems.org for your application to run.

I faced this issue too, then later came to know that the site was down for that particular period of time.

Note - Your error is most probably due to missing header files on your local machine. First, install the SQL and Ruby header files, then try `bundle install` again.

Comment: Please spell out "you", for readability. Being "l33t" will make people discount what you have to say because you aren't taking the time to write legibly. Remember, employers and potential ones read these answers too.

Comment: Will keep that in mind in future , thanks for pointing out :)